# Unsupported version Error in Jmeter response with AMF protocol

Tags: flash, jmeter, performance-testing, amf

I am trying to automate a flash application which uses the AMF protocol.
This is how my request looks like:

```
null/1à

Mflex.messaging.messages.CommandMessageoperationcorrelationIdtimestamp  bodyclientIdheadersmessageIdtimeToLivedestination

%DSMessagingVersion DSIdnilI12B07F2A-960E-8674-0B30-098C3C977AB1
```

This is my response attached

[response image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNHD1.png):

I have tried to send the request in XML format as well, but same error message in response. Am I missing any other steps (like any AMF jar files etc.,) to make the flash application work with Jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter per se doesn't support AMF protocol, my expectation is that you need i.e. [JMeter AMF Plugin](https://github.com/steeltomato/jmeter-amf)

You will need to have [BlazeDS libraries](https://flex.apache.org/download-blazeds.html) in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) as well.

Check out [How to Load Test Flex and AMF Protocol Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-load-test-flex-and-amf-protocol-apps-with-jmeter) article for more information on plugins installation and usage if needed.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter does not support AMF testing.

You can try this commercial plugin for JMeter that transforms binary format to XML and reverse.

https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/load-testing-flex-with-jmeter-made-easy/

Disclaimer : It is developed by our company